# backgrid.js delete selected

Tags: javascript, backgrid

I am trying to add a delete button to a datagrid (using backgrid.js http://backgridjs.com/)

I have a select row

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: [{

    // name is a required parameter, but you don't really want one on a select all column
    name: "id",

    // Backgrid.Extension.SelectRowCell lets you select individual rows
    cell: "select-row",

  }].concat(columns),
  collection: contacts
});
```

a button:

```
<button id= "button" type="button">Delete</button>
```

and:

```
$('#button').click(function () {

});
```

but how do i get the selected row id ? and send it to the server, to delete data from DB?

Comment: Backbone.Collection#remove or Grid#removeRow, have you tried this ?

Comment: no, I don't get it, how it works ... some examples ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an entry on the [documentation](http://backgridjs.com/ref/extensions/select-all.html#manipulating-selections-programatically) describing `Grid#getSelectedModels`.